# Image caption and cross referenceing in Beamer poster

Tags: graphics, captions, beamerposter

In my beamer poster, I like to give caption for images and cross reference that in writing like my thesis ("Figure 2.1: Text" like this)

[image].

But when I use the following code, I found ("Figure: Text" Like this)

[image]

and in the cross reference position shows "Fig.1". 
-I like to write the caption like "Figure A: Text" and in writing cross reference it like "(Fig. A)". Is it possible to do?

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=120,scale=1.7,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,color,pgf}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,amsthm,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}


\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{ \centering#2\par}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{textblock}{}(0.2,6.2)%
\begin{varblock}[57cm]{}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Figure/LB.jpg}
\caption{TExt}
\label{LB}
\end{figure}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{}(4.15,8.7)%
\begin{varblock}[28cm]{\textbf{Location B}}
\ref{LB} shows...
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `caption` template to be numbered and then you can cross-reference your figure:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

Your code:

```
\documentclass[final, 12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=120,height=120,scale=1.7,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig,color,pgf}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx,amsthm,multirow,amsmath}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{ \centering#2\par}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{textblock}{}(0.2,6.2)%
\begin{varblock}[57cm]{}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Figure/LB.jpg}
\caption{TExt}
\label{LB}
\end{figure}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{}(4.15,8.7)%
\begin{varblock}[28cm]{\textbf{Location B}}
Figure~\ref{LB} shows...
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```