# Can I place a caption inside of an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, transparency

I've recently seen this the following image in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56136/5645):

[image]

As I was looking for a way to create nice captions (without the "Figure:") for a beamer presentation, I wondered if it was possible to create this effect within LaTeX.

I got so far with GIMP:

[image]
[image]

I did it like this:

1. add a white layer where the caption will go and set it's transparancy to 50%
2. gaussian blur on the image where the caption will go
   3 add the caption

Can I do this within LaTeX, too?

I have a couple of images which I would like to include in a beamer presentation like this, so it would be great if this worked.

(I've tried a google image search for this, but "latex caption" seems not to be good ... even when I filter explicit results)

### My try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{foto-martin.jpg}};
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
            \draw[white, fill=white!50!transparent] (0,0.05) rectangle (1,0.1);
            \node at (0.5, 0.075) {\Huge Martin};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to get the transparency / positioning working.

As somebody suggested imagemagick, I tried this:

```
width=`identify -format %w foto-martin.jpg`;     convert         -background '#0008'         -fill white         -gravity center         -size ${width}x40             caption:"Martin"             foto-martin.jpg +swap         -gravity south         -geometry +0+10        -composite  out.jpg
```

But I can't get some padding for the text in the caption and the box arround.

Comment: I'd bet that a tikz-based solution is going to appear here within 30 minutes;).  (Would do it myself if I had time now.) Edit: though the blur would be a problem.

Comment: Idea II: `\write18` and ImageMagick.

Comment: @mbork: I'm working on it, I don't know how to make this half-transparent overlay and the positioning

Comment: Idea III: I guess that even the blur is doable (though inefficiently) with tikz - just clip the right part of the translation of the picture a few times and put it with suitable opacity settings.  Though I'd go with ImageMagick and either `\write18` or a Makefile (or arara, or whatever like that).

Comment: see chapter 20 of tikz manual, this might help.

Comment: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559)

Comment: @cmhughes: Thank you very much! The positioning-problem is now almost fixed :-)

Comment: @cmhughes: good point, I forgot about that question - but the blur is the hard part here, I guess;).  (And transparency, to much lesser degree.)

Comment: @moose Writing your name on your forehead is the equivalent of putting a caption inside a picture:-) I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: OTOH, you might want to put some text on a (blurred) part of the picture and make it semi-transparent, so I find the question more general-purpose and very good indeed.  One application that comes to mind is a calendar on a photograph.  (I did something like that in Gimp, with pictures of my daughter for my parents, and it was an instant hit;).)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I have to do a presentation about a project. This includes showing five team members. I would like to do it on one slide. This means, I don't have much space for captions below. Additionally, I think this looks very good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that this question isn't a duplicate of [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) you can achieve what you want by using the `opacity=<value>` key, where value can be anything between `0` (invisible) and `1` (completely visible).

[image: screenshot]

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mushroom}};
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
            \draw[white, fill=gray,opacity=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.15);
            \node[opacity=0.5] at (0.5, 0.075) {\Huge Mushroom};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Arrgh.... I wait a little the delete mine eheh. That mushroom is magic!

Comment: There is no blurred effect!

Comment: @cmhughes: I didn't know `opacity=0.5`. Thank you!

Comment: I've adjusted some values a little bit. May I edit your solution? As I applied your solution to my presentation, I noticed that I have to choose the adjust the font size manually. Not that was a big problem ...
Here is [the result](http://i.imgur.com/qgTDbDq.png)

Comment: I'd like to give +2 because from all the captions in this thread so far, this one looks the most beautiful, blur effect or not.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an approach that uses ImageMagick to blur the image and place a clipped version on top of the unblurred image (which requires `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` to call the external program). The whole thing is wrapped in a macro called `\labelimage{<file name>}{<image width>}{<label text>}`. The background rectangle style can be set using `image label background/.style`, the label node uses `image label text/.style`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    image label text/.style={
        white, font=\sffamily
    },
    image label background/.style={
        white, opacity=0.35
    }
}
\newcommand{\labelimage}[3]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \immediate\write18{convert #1 -blur 0x3 blurred#1}
        \node [inner sep=0pt] (original) {\includegraphics[#2]{#1}};
        \begin{scope}[
            fill=white,
            shift=(original.south west),
            x=(original.south east),
            y=(original.north west)
        ]
        \fill [clip] (0,0.05) rectangle (1,0.25);
            \node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] {\includegraphics[#2]{blurred#1}};
            \fill [image label background] (0,0.05) rectangle (1,0.25)
                node [text opacity=1, pos=0.5, image label text] {#3};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\labelimage{martin.jpg}{width=4em}{Martin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Your solution requires `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18`...

Comment: Could you adjust your solution so that I can resize the image? I would like to call it like `\labelimage[width=0.3\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{foto-martin.jpg}{Martin}`. I've also noticed that relative paths like `../images/foto-peter.jpg` seem not to work.