# Labeling and adding caption inside a figure

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing, transparency

Seems like this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101196/412) is rather closed. However, I feel that something is missing there.

Inside a `figure` environment, the `\caption` alone is nice, but its real power comes from the combination with `\label`. This is what enables the user to enumerate the graphics in his/her document automatically and establish cross references.

Is it possible to combine everything together?

That is, have a figure which is something like:

```
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|       <The figure>        |
|                           |
| Figure 1. And its caption |
|---------------------------|
```

and labeled using `\label{fig:1}`, such that its caption is embedded in the figure itself (like the wonderful possibilities offered in the answers to the linked question). Then have something like `\ref{fig:1}` to refer to this figure.

Is it possible to automate this? Somehow, let hand-coded caption communicate with the `\caption`+`\label`+`\ref` mechanism. I have to say that I don't even know where to start addressing this issue.

Comment: Can you give more indication about what the question is? I have to say I don't understand it at all. In the accepted answer to the linked question the caption is not embedded in the image file it is just typeset with latex/tikz but overlayed over the image, but caption/label would just work as normal.

Comment: Perhaps the package *textpos* could be useful for your purpose. Check the manual [HERE](http://nxg.me.uk/dist/textpos/) and look for the option **overlay**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package to set up a style, lets call it `overlay` that saves the caption for use later.  Here is an example:

*EDIT* example technique slightly change, example extended, now working with `hyperref`

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{overlay}{\gdef\capoverlay{#1#2#3\par}}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{overlay}{format=overlay}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{format=overlay}
  \caption{Example.}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
      \draw[white, fill=gray,opacity=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.15);
      \draw let \p1 = (1,0)
      in node[opacity=0.5,text width=\x1,align=center,color=white] at
      (0.5, 0.075) 
      {\capoverlay};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Non-overlay example}
  \label{fig:non}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{format=overlay}
  \caption{Example with caption overlay and long placed on a smaller figure.}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
      \draw[white, fill=gray,opacity=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,0.15);
      \draw let \p1 = (1,0)
      in node[opacity=0.5,text width=\x1,align=center,color=blue] at
      (0.5, 0.075) 
      {\capoverlay};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:example2}
\end{figure}

A reference to Figure~\ref{fig:example} and to Figure~\ref{fig:example2}.

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Note this needs the caption to come before the `tikz` code.  It formats the caption, saves it in a command and reuses that command in the code of the linked question to place text on top of the figure.  As set-up now this works with `hyperref` and does not affect other figures.  You can change the formatting of the caption via standard `tikz` commands on the node.